# Generally speaking, given two CFTs, how can we check that they are equivalent?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory

We can calculate their central charges. And beyond this, are there some other general approaches?

Or we must find an isomorphism of operators between the two theories?

Comment: Of course one should compare operator content as well.